# Setting destination on Uber web application

Tags: uber-api

Looks like https://m.uber.com is a fully functional web application for requesting Uber rides. Are there any URL parameters I can provide to pre-set things like the destination of the ride?

I was looking at the developer documentation, but it seems to be focused on using the API or embedding the widget in iOS or Android apps.

Answer (score 2):

No, I am not aware of setting the destination for m.uber.com. If you are using our sdk or widgets you can use deep links. Find out more about deep links here: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-standard

Comment: Thanks. In this case I would like to be able to do everything on a desktop, so there is no linking to the mobile app

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an Android app, you can use UberWebAppLauncher
https://github.com/enesinky/uberwebapplauncher

```
UberWebAppLauncher uberWebAppLauncher = new UberWebAppLauncher()  
 .setPickupLocation(37.775837823803705, -122.41803507478294, "1455 Market St #400, San Francisco, CA 94103, United States", "Uber HQ")  
 .setDropoffLocation(37.78618285698499, -122.40003724864789, "151 3rd St, San Francisco, CA 94103, United States", "San Francisco Museum of Modern Art")  
 .build();  
  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uberWebAppLauncher.getUri());  
startActivity(intent); // open the url in web browser
```